# Error de sintaxis al importar base da datos mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Tengo un problema al importar una base de datos mysql en phpmyadmin, se me descompusó de la nada el módulo de mysql y tuve que borrar el xampp y volverlo a instalar, pero a la hora de importar la copia de seguridad de mi base de datos me da este error y no entiendo a que se debe si `drop table if exists 'alumnos'` es la primera línea y ya comprobé que no haya caracteres invisibles ni esas cosas:

> Análisis estático:
>
> Se encontraron 49 errores durante el análisis.
>
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 1)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 3)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 5)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 7)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 9)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 11)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 13)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 15)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 17)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 19)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 21)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 23)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 25)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 27)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 29)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 31)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 33)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 35)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 37)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 39)
> Caracter inesperado. (near "" at position 41)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "D" at position 0)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 1)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "R" at position 2)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 3)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "O" at position 4)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 5)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "P" at position 6)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 7)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 9)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "T" at position 10)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 11)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "A" at position 12)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 13)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "B" at position 14)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 15)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "L" at position 16)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 17)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "E" at position 18)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 19)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 21)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "I" at position 22)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 23)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "F" at position 24)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 25)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 27)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "E" at position 28)
> Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "" at position 29)
> Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "X" at position 30)
> consulta SQL: Copiar
>
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `alumnos`;
>
> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'D' en la linea 1

Este es el código de mi archivo `copia.sql`

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `alumnos`;

CREATE TABLE `alumnos` (
  `id_alumno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_p` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_m` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexo` enum('H','M') NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nac` date NOT NULL,
  `apoyo_par` decimal(3,1) DEFAULT 1.0,
  `grupo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_alumno`),
  KEY `grupo` (`grupo`),
  CONSTRAINT `grupo` FOREIGN KEY (`grupo`) REFERENCES `grupos` (`id_grupo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `alumnos` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;

DELIMITER ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `alumnos-asistencia`;

CREATE TABLE `alumnos-asistencia` (
  `id_aa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alumno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asistencia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asistio` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `retardo` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `student` (`alumno`),
  KEY `asistencia` (`asistencia`),
  CONSTRAINT `asistencia` FOREIGN KEY (`asistencia`) REFERENCES `asistencias` (`id_asist`),
  CONSTRAINT `student` FOREIGN KEY (`alumno`) REFERENCES `alumnos` (`id_alumno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



LOCK TABLES `alumnos-asistencia` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `asignaturas`;

CREATE TABLE `asignaturas` (
  `id_asign` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `horas_sem` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `planificaci├│n` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d├¡as_sem` set('lunes','martes','mi├®rcoles','jueves','viernes') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_asign`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

LOCK TABLES `asignaturas` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `asistencias`;

CREATE TABLE `asistencias` (
  `id_asist` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_asist`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;




LOCK TABLES `asistencias` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `calificaciones`;

CREATE TABLE `calificaciones` (
  `id_cal` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alumno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asignatura` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calificaci├│n` float(3,1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cal`),
  KEY `alumno` (`alumno`),
  KEY `asignatura` (`asignatura`),
  CONSTRAINT `alumno` FOREIGN KEY (`alumno`) REFERENCES `alumnos` (`id_alumno`),
  CONSTRAINT `asignatura` FOREIGN KEY (`asignatura`) REFERENCES `asignaturas` (`id_asign`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `calificaciones` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fotos`;

CREATE TABLE `fotos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `fotos` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `fotos` VALUES (1,'FOTOS\\\\heroaltair2@gmail.com\\\\heroaltair2@gmail.com-1687562791700.png');

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `grupos`;

CREATE TABLE `grupos` (
  `id_grupo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grado` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6') NOT NULL,
  `nombre` enum('A','B','C') NOT NULL,
  `profesor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_alumnos` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_grupo`),
  KEY `profesor` (`profesor`),
  CONSTRAINT `profesor` FOREIGN KEY (`profesor`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `grupos` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `grupos-asignaturas`;

CREATE TABLE `grupos-asignaturas` (
  `id_ga` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grupo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asignatura` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ga`),
  KEY `groups` (`grupo`),
  KEY `subject` (`asignatura`),
  CONSTRAINT `groups` FOREIGN KEY (`grupo`) REFERENCES `grupos` (`id_grupo`),
  CONSTRAINT `subject` FOREIGN KEY (`asignatura`) REFERENCES `asignaturas` (`id_asign`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;




LOCK TABLES `grupos-asignaturas` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `profesores`;

CREATE TABLE `profesores` (
  `id_prof` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clave_sp` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_p` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_m` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_prof`),
  UNIQUE KEY `clave_sp` (`clave_sp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `profesores` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `profesores` VALUES (1,'000000000','Montserrat','Flor├¡n','Gonz├ílez');;
UNLOCK TABLES;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tokens`;
CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
  `id_token` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_expiraci├│n` datetime NOT NULL,
  `usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_token`),
  KEY `usuario` (`usuario`),
  CONSTRAINT `usuario` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;




LOCK TABLES `tokens` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `tokens` VALUES (1,'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiQWxlamFuZHJvIiwibGFzdF9uYW1lIjoiU8OhbmNoZXoiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFsZWphbmRyb3NhbmNoZXpiMDhAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg2MTk1MDI3LCJleHAiOiIyMDIzLTA2LTA4VDAzOjQwOjI3Ljc4NFoifQ.22pwknYsP2-epCGEmBld4noYowdoGCBjLYw8DR3_794','2023-06-07 22:40:27',2),(2,'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiS2V2aW4gSm9mcmFseSIsImxhc3RfbmFtZSI6IlDDqXJleiAiLCJlbWFpbCI6Imhlcm9hbHRhaXIyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY4NTY4NjA2NCwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMy0wNi0wMlQwNjoxNzo0NC44NjBaIn0.QqmBuje74Mnc-mtqBLr3xha1tQtQVidWkXrlfbljc6E','2023-06-02 01:17:44',1);

UNLOCK TABLES;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usuarios`;

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_p` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_m` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rol` enum('usuario','administrador') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'usuario',
  `verificado` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

LOCK TABLES `usuarios` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES (1,'Kevin Jofraly','P├®rez ','L├│pez','heroaltair2@gmail.com','$2b$10$XFj3hfrApHgq55FzKN114eINy22I7/lZygsY1dh2ixyZkGy.2yYxi','administrador',1),(2,'Alejandro','S├ínchez',NULL,'alejandrosanchezb08@gmail.com','$2b$10$rCIuzHQE09GBUSVbqjJSROYxHDX8yNzSrIYMTXXE9W.ocr0TFlYwy','usuario',1),(3,'Jaciel Emauz','P├®rez','L├│pez','thespecter06@gmail.com','$2b$10$KfIIhhmBIRx/Tixm99/c8Ocmy9s532KFrbkboBwByuiC/R1YSVhAy','usuario',0);

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vista_alumnos_grupo`;

SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;

SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vista_grupo`;

SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;

SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

Comment: Hay varias formas de respaldar/recuperar. ¿Cómo hiciste la copia de seguridad?. ¿Cómo intentas hacer la recuperación?.

Comment: Hice la copia de seguridad mediante línea de comandos usando mysqldump ya que la versión de xampp que tenía estaba bugeada y me daba error al hacerlo desde la interfaz gráfica, la recuperación si la estoy haciendo mediante GUI en la pestaña importar de phpmyadmin

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta las versiones de MySQL tanto de origen como destino.

Answer (score 1):

Es por el orden de creación de las tablas. El Script que pones ha hecho todo en orden alfabético tal cual se ordenan en la DB. Pero esas tablas tienen **FOREIGN KEYs** y por lo mismo no se pueden crear porque las tablas a las que dichas **FOREIGN KEYs** hacen referencia NO EXISTEN aun en la DB.

Solución? usar el script en base a como se creó el esquema de la DB. Yo logré restaurar tu script, no digo que sea la forma correcta pero no me dio problemas, ya tu puedes solventar los problemas futuros.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `usuarios`;

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_p` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_m` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rol` enum('usuario','administrador') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'usuario',
  `verificado` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

LOCK TABLES `usuarios` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES (1,'Kevin Jofraly','P├®rez ','L├│pez','heroaltair2@gmail.com','$2b$10$XFj3hfrApHgq55FzKN114eINy22I7/lZygsY1dh2ixyZkGy.2yYxi','administrador',1),(2,'Alejandro','S├ínchez',NULL,'alejandrosanchezb08@gmail.com','$2b$10$rCIuzHQE09GBUSVbqjJSROYxHDX8yNzSrIYMTXXE9W.ocr0TFlYwy','usuario',1),(3,'Jaciel Emauz','P├®rez','L├│pez','thespecter06@gmail.com','$2b$10$KfIIhhmBIRx/Tixm99/c8Ocmy9s532KFrbkboBwByuiC/R1YSVhAy','usuario',0);

UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `profesores`;

CREATE TABLE `profesores` (
  `id_prof` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clave_sp` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_p` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_m` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_prof`),
  UNIQUE KEY `clave_sp` (`clave_sp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `profesores` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `profesores` VALUES (1,'000000000','Montserrat','Flor├¡n','Gonz├ílez');;
UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `grupos`;

CREATE TABLE `grupos` (
  `id_grupo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grado` enum('1','2','3','4','5','6') NOT NULL,
  `nombre` enum('A','B','C') NOT NULL,
  `profesor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total_alumnos` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_grupo`),
  KEY `profesor` (`profesor`),
  CONSTRAINT `profesor` FOREIGN KEY (`profesor`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `grupos` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `alumnos`;

CREATE TABLE `alumnos` (
  `id_alumno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_p` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_m` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexo` enum('H','M') NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nac` date NOT NULL,
  `apoyo_par` decimal(3,1) DEFAULT 1.0,
  `grupo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_alumno`),
  KEY `grupo` (`grupo`),
  CONSTRAINT `grupo` FOREIGN KEY (`grupo`) REFERENCES `grupos` (`id_grupo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `alumnos` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;

DELIMITER ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `asistencias`;

CREATE TABLE `asistencias` (
  `id_asist` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_asist`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `asistencias` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `alumnos-asistencia`;

CREATE TABLE `alumnos-asistencia` (
  `id_aa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alumno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asistencia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asistio` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `retardo` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `student` (`alumno`),
  KEY `asistencia` (`asistencia`),
  CONSTRAINT `asistencia` FOREIGN KEY (`asistencia`) REFERENCES `asistencias` (`id_asist`),
  CONSTRAINT `student` FOREIGN KEY (`alumno`) REFERENCES `alumnos` (`id_alumno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `alumnos-asistencia` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `asignaturas`;

CREATE TABLE `asignaturas` (
  `id_asign` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `horas_sem` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `planificaci├│n` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d├¡as_sem` set('lunes','martes','mi├®rcoles','jueves','viernes') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_asign`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

LOCK TABLES `asignaturas` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `calificaciones`;

CREATE TABLE `calificaciones` (
  `id_cal` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alumno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asignatura` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calificaci├│n` float(3,1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cal`),
  KEY `alumno` (`alumno`),
  KEY `asignatura` (`asignatura`),
  CONSTRAINT `alumno` FOREIGN KEY (`alumno`) REFERENCES `alumnos` (`id_alumno`),
  CONSTRAINT `asignatura` FOREIGN KEY (`asignatura`) REFERENCES `asignaturas` (`id_asign`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `calificaciones` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fotos`;

CREATE TABLE `fotos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `fotos` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `fotos` VALUES (1,'FOTOS\\\\heroaltair2@gmail.com\\\\heroaltair2@gmail.com-1687562791700.png');

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `grupos-asignaturas`;

CREATE TABLE `grupos-asignaturas` (
  `id_ga` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grupo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `asignatura` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ga`),
  KEY `groups` (`grupo`),
  KEY `subject` (`asignatura`),
  CONSTRAINT `groups` FOREIGN KEY (`grupo`) REFERENCES `grupos` (`id_grupo`),
  CONSTRAINT `subject` FOREIGN KEY (`asignatura`) REFERENCES `asignaturas` (`id_asign`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `grupos-asignaturas` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tokens`;
CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
  `id_token` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_expiraci├│n` datetime NOT NULL,
  `usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_token`),
  KEY `usuario` (`usuario`),
  CONSTRAINT `usuario` FOREIGN KEY (`usuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


LOCK TABLES `tokens` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `tokens` VALUES (1,'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiQWxlamFuZHJvIiwibGFzdF9uYW1lIjoiU8OhbmNoZXoiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFsZWphbmRyb3NhbmNoZXpiMDhAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg2MTk1MDI3LCJleHAiOiIyMDIzLTA2LTA4VDAzOjQwOjI3Ljc4NFoifQ.22pwknYsP2-epCGEmBld4noYowdoGCBjLYw8DR3_794','2023-06-07 22:40:27',2),(2,'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiS2V2aW4gSm9mcmFseSIsImxhc3RfbmFtZSI6IlDDqXJleiAiLCJlbWFpbCI6Imhlcm9hbHRhaXIyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY4NTY4NjA2NCwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMy0wNi0wMlQwNjoxNzo0NC44NjBaIn0.QqmBuje74Mnc-mtqBLr3xha1tQtQVidWkXrlfbljc6E','2023-06-02 01:17:44',1);

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vista_alumnos_grupo`;

SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;

SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vista_grupo`;

SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;

SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```